# How to debug typescript&react files(.tsx) in vscode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using [this](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) project template. And i set a breakpoint into App class in App.tsx file. Shared configurations below. nothing look wrong but it doesnt work even "F5" not trigg anything.

I searched many but couldnt find any proper solution..
launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [

        {
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "name": "DEBUG",
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/build/dist",
            "preLaunchTask": "compile",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/App.tsx",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
```

here is debug config name and breakpoint:
[image]

and working directory:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unable to debug it because the application you are running is client side (executed in browser) whereas out of the box VSCode supports debugging of the server side (nodejs for example) typescript applications.

You can debug your app by installing the [Debugger for Chrome](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) extension and following their guidelines.

Or as alternative - debug it inside chrome using its dev tools.